# Reinstalling Windows 10: Cleaning boot partition but keeping my files on another partition. Will it work?

Tags: windows-10, partitioning

I want to reinstall Windows 10 but I have a lot of files on my hard drive and no external hard drive to move the files to. So I thought I'd create another partition and move the files there, and then clean the boot partition, leaving my files safe on the other partition. Can someone confirm that my assumption is correct, that the files are indeed "safe" on another partition? I don't want to lose them and I don't have time to get an external drive.

Comment: "Safe" is a relative term if you have no backup. They're "safe" so long as you don't do anything wrong. Why work with no safety-net, why not wait until you have a known-good backup?

Comment: *and then clean the system partition* ??? System partition in most cases is relatively  small partition whict is primary/bootable and contains boot loader files. Maybe you mean boot partition - the partition where OS is stored, where Windows, Program Files and another OS folders are posessed?

Comment: *Can someone confirm that my assumption is correct, that the files are indeed "safe" on another partition?* OS installer should not change the partition which is not specified as a partition where this OS must be installed onto. But I'd avoid to guarantee that this place is really safe, because "shit happens"..

Comment: @Akina Yes, I meant the boot partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that can work and is a common use case. I have done that before myself. If one has more than one operating system, it can be useful to store user data in a different partition, separately from the OS data.

That being said, I would strongly recommend backing up your data before doing this. It's too easy to select the wrong partition during installation. If you have a decent internet connection, maybe consider backing up your data to something like google drive or Dropbox. With google drive 100 GB is 2 USD and 2 TB is 10 USD for a month, cancel when your done.

There is nothing technically preventing you from doing this. There is just the risk of you making a mistake.

Comment: Ah yes, the common use case of BAKING a pie out of my data. Shame I didn't BACK them up :)

Comment: lol, thank you for the spot. (baking -> backing)